# How would i create an ActiveMQ Producer programatically in Java for Mule?

Tags: java, activemq-classic, mule

I got a doubt about this, i've created an ActiveMQ Connector with its Connector-Reference as well:

```
<jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ" specification="1.1" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" validateConnections="false"  doc:name="Active MQ" >
    <reconnect count="5"  />
</jms:activemq-connector>
```

I know i can get this by doing from Java:

```
Connector amqConnector = eventContext.getMuleContext().getRegistry().lookupConnector("Active_MQ");
```

But how would i create the producer by using this connector data and not by using JNDI? All the tutorials i've read they use the InitialContext getting the JNDI props by doing lookup().

Also, in my ActiveMQ Config File i'm creating the queue. So the Queue its already created, i only need the producer to access to that Queue and not create it.

And would my queueName be in the ActiveMQConnection "DestinationSource"? How do i get the queue names or info inside the activemq config file from Java?

///// ADDED AFTER DAVID'S HELP:

This is what i currently have:

```
@Override
    public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
        String payload = eventContext.getMessage().getPayloadAsString();
        JmsConnector amqConnector = (JmsConnector) eventContext.getMuleContext().getRegistry().lookupConnector("Active_MQ");
        ConnectionFactory factory = amqConnector.getConnectionFactory();
        Connection connection; 

        connection = factory.createConnection();

        try {
            connection.start();
            Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            Queue queue = session.createQueue("ExampleQueue");

            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);           
            producer.send(session.createTextMessage(payload), DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT, 0, 5000);

        }finally {
            connection.close();
        }

        return eventContext;
    }
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a connection factory a go from there:

```
Connection connection = amqConnector.getConnectionFactory().createConnection();
Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
Queue queue = session.createQueue("yourQueue");
MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);
...
```

Don't worry about `session.createQueue`: it's not going to re-create the existing queue, it's just going to use it.

Comment: Yep, did the following:
JmsConnector amqConnector = (JmsConnector) eventContext.getMuleContext().getRegistry().lookupConnector("Active_MQ");
  ConnectionFactory factory = amqConnector.getConnectionFactory();
  Connection connection; 
  
  connection = factory.createConnection();

Thanks David, always helpful! :D

Comment: another question David, what if i want to set the request-response exchange pattern via Java? o.O this error was thrown Could not find a transformer to transform "SimpleDataType{type=org.mule.DefaultMuleEventContext, mimeType='*/*'}" to "SimpleDataType{type=org.mule.api.transport.OutputHandler, mimeType='*/*'}"

Comment: added the current code, David. Can't set the exchange pattern in the session nor producer.